# How to slide up and slide down in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a simple toggle example in AngularJS. I am facing one issue I need to show and hide with some animation like slide up and slide down. I have `search` button on header on click I show search `div` it is working in my plunker. My issue is to do animation...

Secondly I need to add `z-index` because it generates new layer. When I click search button **"my name "**  come down when search bar is open. Why?

```
<ion-view>
<ion-header-bar align-title="" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
  <i style="font-size:25px!important" class="icon-right ion-android-radio-button-off" ng-click="showsearch()"></i>

  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
  <a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-calm"></a>
</ion-header-bar>
<div class="list list-inset searchclass" ng-show="isdiplay">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/n2s5u9eifp3y2rz/search_icon.png?dl=0">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
  </label>
</div>
<ion-contend>
  <div style="margin-top:50px">
  my name
</div>
</ion-contend>

</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using Angular you still have the opportunity to use plain old CSS transitions. However, there are many ways to animate elements. In my solution here I use `ng-class` instead of `ng-show`. I toggle the class `active` when ever you click on the trigger. Finally the class changes the state of the element which results in the animation you would like to achieve.

You could simply change `ng-show` to `ng-class="{'active':isdiplay}"` and add the following CSS:

```
.searchclass {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 !important;
  position: relative;
  top: 44px;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.searchclass.active {
  height: 49px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

You can however, as I said before, also use `ng-show` with the module `ngAnimate` which needs to be included in one of your own modules. This will enable animations out of the box, so that elements which can be animated get classes such as `.ng-hide-remove`, `.ng-hide-add` and `.ng-hide-add-active` etc. You could then style those classes on your own.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']).controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.isdiplay = false;
  $scope.showsearch = function() {
    $scope.isdiplay = !$scope.isdiplay;
  }
})
```

```css
.searchclass {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 !important;
  position: relative;
  top: 44px;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.searchclass.active {
  height: 49px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ionicApp" ng-controller="MyController">
<ion-view>
  <ion-header-bar align-title="" class="bar-positive">
    <div class="buttons">
      <i style="font-size:25px!important" class="icon-right ion-android-radio-button-off" ng-click="showsearch()"></i>
    </div>
    <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
    <a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-calm"></a>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <div class="list list-inset searchclass" ng-class="{'active':isdiplay}">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/n2s5u9eifp3y2rz/search_icon.png?dl=0">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </label>
  </div>
  <ion-contend>
    <div style="margin-top:50px">
      my name
    </div>
  </ion-contend>
</ion-view>  
</div>
```